# How to install OpenMotif on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, citrix

There is no package called `openmotif`, so how do I install it on Ubuntu 12.04? It's needed according to Citrix, for using Citrix Receiver 12.1 for Linux.

Comment: if you got the source package then it will consists of README and INSTALL files and they gonna help you through the install .

Answer (score 4):

Installation should be as simple as installing the `libmotif-dev` package. So

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

To install OpenMotif for Citrix, check out the [CitrixICAClientHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo)

Comment: What about installing the package called "libmotif4"? Will that do the trick?

Comment: I really have not tried that, but you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install packages `libmotif4` & `nspluginwrapper` (you can use synaptic package manager)
2. Download the Receiver you need from [citrix.com](http://receiver.citrix.com/) (.deb file)
3. Open the downloaded file
4. Add the certificates to avoid SSL error

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

in some cases packages for ubuntu are named little bit differently

1. so you need to search by package name
2. or to search for package contents

   `apt-cache search 'pattern'`
   `apt-file search 'path'`

this is a universal solution